# Blazor not detecting Model has updated

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Im currently having an issue where after I fetch data from my api, the view still seems to think the data is null. Please see below code:

View:

```
@if (goals == null)
{
    <Loader />
}
else if (goals.Count == 0)
{
    <div class="center-text">
        <h2>It doesn't look like you have any goals create yet!</h2>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h1>found stuff!</h1>
}

@functions {
List<GoalViewModel> goals;

protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
    var token = await LocalStorage.GetItem<string>("AuthToken");
    var httpClient = HttpClientExtensions.GetAuthHttpClient(token);
    goals = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<List<GoalViewModel>>(ClientSettings.GetHostRoot() + "/api/Goals/");
}
}
```

the controller action being hit looks like the following (I've verified that it is being called correctly and is returning data via the chrome network tab and fiddler):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var goalIndexDtos = _goalManager.GetAll(_claimResolver.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
                var goalViewModels = Mapper.Map<List<GoalViewModel>>(goalIndexDtos);

                return Ok(goalViewModels);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(FormatError(nameof(GoalsController), nameof(Get), ex));
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }
```

My issue is that the `<Loader />` always displays whereas I should be seeing a `<h1>found stuff!</h1>` since my controller is returning data appropriately and the blazor view code is successfully deserializing the data.

What am I missing here? I'm doing very similar things in other places in my application and they seem to work fine. I've compared this use case to the others over and over and don't see anything different.

I've even stuck a `Console.WriteLine(goals.Count);` line after the call to retrieve goals from the server and it correctly prints `1` to the console.

UPDATE: after playing around with everything I could think of, I deleted all data from the db table that `goals` is being retrieved from. this returns an empty list from my controller. In this case `<h2>It doesn't look like you have any goals create yet!</h2>` does print as expected! HOWEVER, the second I add a row and a list of count 1 is returned, all I get is a loader

SOLVED: After cleaning, building, rebuilding and closing/opening visual studio multiple times, my issue remained. It was only after restarting my machine that this began to work as expected.

Comment: Is it a typo that goals is not declared?

Comment: yes, sorry about that - updated my post. specifically the `@functions {...}` section

Comment: It should do it for you, but have you tried calling StateHasChanged() after the call to fetch goals?

Comment: I have, `StateHasChanged()` throws an exception. I can update the answer with the full exception if it's of interest to you

Comment: restarting my machine solved the issue... sigh

Comment: I was honestly about to make a joke "have you tried turning it off and on again" since blazor is supposed to update.... but OH MY!!! it actually worked